# Scala Array - index issue

Tags: arrays, scala

I have the below Array with me.

```
scala> var a1 =Array(1.1,2.4,3.6)
a1: Array[Double] = Array(1.1, 2.4, 3.6)
```

I need to get the index from this array based on the input value as below.Basically, I need two index for a three element array.

For ex- all the input between 1.1 and 2.4 should be in first bucket.
and all the input between 2.5 and 3.6 should be in second bucket.

```
> 1.1 -> 0
> 1.5 -> 0
> 2.4 -> 1
> 3.5 -> 1
> 3.6 -> 1
```

I was trying this using `a1.indexWhere(x <= _)`. But this will result in the last item ie, 3.6 will fall in 3rd index.

Is there any simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: I do not understand the logic of the expected output. Can you clarify how that index is computed?

Comment: If I understand correctly given x you want the index of the value that is <= x? What happens if x is < the first element in the array or larger than the last element?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: For ex- all the input between 1.1 and 2.4 should be in first bucket. and all the input between 2.5 and 3.6 should be in second bucket.

Comment: @Terry then it should fall in first and last bucket respectively. Thats what I am trying to get here.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - the logic for the upper and lower bounds must be consistent, i.e inclusive or exclusive

Comment: @Terry, My idea was the input values lesser than the first element of array should fit in first index and the same logic holds for the last element,

Comment: With all due respect that doesn't sound like a very good idea. If a value is outside a range it shouldn't be considered a member. The -1 returned in these cases by indexWhere seems more reasonable if a little old school.

Answer (score 1):

Scala doesn't have a function for that behavior exclusively. Try this simple solution:

```
val tempIndex = a1.indexWhere(x <= _)
if (tempIndex == a1.length - 1) tempIndex - 1 else tempIndex
```

Test it [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/zN2TsHI/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. For anything not in a bucket you will get -1.

```
a1.zip(a.tail).indexWhere{ case (min, max) => x > min && x <= max}
```